# Hurricane / lose strenght / die down / weakens / fade out / abates

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

how to describe when a hurricane ends and disappears?

- Lose strength
- die down
- weakens
- fade out
- abates

In Russia using "subsides" but one-way translate doesn't work

Comment: 'Die down', 'abate', 'lose strength' and 'weaken' are fairly common. The first might imply complete ending, the others just a reduction in strength. Have you tried any Google searches using your example phrases?

Comment: I tried searching how uses in TV news but confused.

Comment: Try these Google searches, using the quote marks "Hurricane died down", "Hurricane abated", ""Hurricane lost strength", "Hurricane weakened". You will see that all are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these are possible, but one slightly more technical term that is used by (for example) the National Hurricane Center is "dissipate"  This means that the storm breaks up and ceases to exist.

> Hurricanes dissipate for a variety of reasons. They weaken quickly over land... ([source](https://ocean.si.edu/planet-ocean/waves-storms-tsunamis/hurricanes-typhoons-and-cyclones#:%7E:text=Hurricanes%20dissipate%20for%20a%20variety,friction%20than%20the%20sea%20surface.))

Of course a storm may weaken without completely dissipating.

You would use words like "abate" or "subside" to describe the strength of the storm in a particular location, rather than the strength of the storm in total.

> The storm winds in Haiti began to subside at midnight, and in the morning the storm had abated.  But the hurricane had simply moved into the Caribean sea, and was continuing to strengthen. Twenty-four hours later it made landfall in Louisiana, causing it to weaken rapidly and dissipate over the following day.  (my example)

(It may also be worth noting, as the translations may not indicate this, that while strong winds are possible, "hurricanes" (in the strict sense) never happen in Russia)

Answer (score 0):

> how to describe when a hurricane ends and disappears?

Out of your choices, *die down* will mean this and news broadcasts would use the term.

The other four choices mean the hurricane loses strength, but still exists.  This might apply if the hurricane travels over land then back out to sea again.

*Fade out* won't really apply to a hurricane--things that *fade* are typically images or feelings.

*Abate* has a scientific connotation and is a word you'll find somewhat more likely in print or prepared/technical speech than natural conversation.

*Lose strength* and *weaken* are equivalent and you'd hear both on the news.